# OutOfMemoryError error occurs when adding vintage junit 5

Tags: java, maven, travis-ci

I translate tests to junit 5. to support tests on junit 4, I added a vintage dependency.
``

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
      <version>5.7.0-M1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.0-M1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
```

Error occurs when building on Travis

```
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Thread-6"
```

I added memory `MAVEN_OPTS='-Xmx1300m'`. the build goes through but still an error appears at the end

```
   [ERROR] Java heap space -> [Help 1]
   [ERROR] 
   [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
   [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
   [ERROR] 
   [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the 
   following articles:
   [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/OutOfMemoryError
```

I don't understand why the error comes out, although the build is going through. Thank you in advance for your answers

Comment: `To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.` Have you tried that? Where the exception originates?

Comment: launched with the addition of -e

``[ERROR] Java heap space -> [Help 1]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange (Arrays.java:3664)
    at java.lang.String.<init> (String.java:207)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString (StringBuilder.java:407)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter$CloseableCloser.run (ForkStarter.java:199)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.shade.org.apache.maven.shared.utils.cli.CommandLineUtils$1.call (CommandLineUtils.java:282)``

Answer (score 1):

the error was due to an incorrect version of the surefire plugin. I put the latest version 3.0.0-M5 and the error disappeared.
@andreoss thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade `maven-surefire-plugin`. This bug [SUREFIRE-1382](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1382) has been fixed in 2.20.1

Comment: I am using maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2